# Deleted Ubuntu partition and can't access Windows any more

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8

I'm a Linux newbie.

I partitioned my HDD and managed to install Ubuntu 15.04 along with my pre-installed Windows 8.1, but when I tried it, it kept crashing and restarting by itself, so I decided to uninstall it to try a different distribution.

I basically deleted the partitions required for Ubuntu (home, swap and root) from Windows, but when I restarted the computer I couldn't boot Windows any more. All I can see is the GRUB2 prompt, and I have no idea how to boot Windows.

Is there something I can do to use my laptop once again? Do I have to reinstall Windows, or can I boot the old OS and access the partition?

Comment: How far you are going to get using just the GRUB prompt depends on whether it managed to load all of GRUB or if you got just the GRUB rescue command line. The GRUB rescue command line can be used to load the rest of GRUB, but that won't help you much if you deleted the rest of GRUB. I didn't find much information about using the GRUB rescue command line when searching, seems most people just boot from USB or CD instead.

Comment: I had the same problem. I found this really simple solution that worked for me. Here is the video I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UY3ojN3F1vw Hope this helps in the future.

Answer (score 6):

If you type `exit` it will then take you back to the options where you can select your Windows Partition.

Doing this will allow you to access your Windows OS and use it as normal temporarily, until you can re-install the Kernals and uninstall Ubuntu properly.

Comment: It won't let me type exit.

Comment: I m very glad I am in this situation to temporary work ! thanks for the  "quick" answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Boot from a Windows 8 recovery Cd/Dvd/Usb.

If you don't have a recovery drive , then you will either have to install the drive into another Windows 8 machine or obtain a Windows 8 recovery drive.

- You will need to choose the `language` and `time settings`.
- Choose `Repair Your Computer`.
- Choose `Troubleshooting`.
- Choose `Advanced Options`.
- Choose `Command Prompt`.

Now, You must use the DISKPART tool to verify that the UEFI partition has a drive letter assignment.

Run:

`DISKPART`

*In this test  we know the disk 0 is our boot HDD*

DISKPART> `sel disk 0`

*Disk 0 is now the selected disk.*

DISKPART> `list vol`

[image]

*We need to assign a drive letter to UEFI partition (volume 3)*

DISKPART> `sel vol 3`

*Volume 3 is the selected volume.*

DISKPART> `assign letter=G:`

*DiskPart successfully assigned the drive letter or mount point.*

Exit DiskPart tool:

DISKPART> `EXIT`

Now, You need to change to the boot folder on the UEFI volume.Depending on the way Windows was installed this path maybe one of the following.

```
cd /d G:\Boot\

cd /d G:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\

cd /d G:\ESD\Windows\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\
```

Now, You will need to enter three command lines to repair the BCD store.

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Comment: Can't agree more. Happened to me once; I've managed with this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You deleted your kernels and GRUB files, so you will not be able to boot anything. Get a Live CD/USB of a distribution you want and install it in that same partition. Then you will be able to boot Windows again.